# Out of memory exception not caught

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I have option to save `Bitmap` to sdcard in my app. 
I am doing saving in `AsyncTask` method. here is what i do on background

```
public File saveImageToExternalStorage(Bitmap image, String name) {
 String fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + APP_PATH_SD_CARD + APP_THUMBNAIL_PATH_SD_CARD;

 try {
 File dir = new File(fullPath);
 if (!dir.exists()) {
 dir.mkdirs();
 }
 OutputStream fOut = null;
 File file = new File(fullPath, name.replaceAll("/", "").trim());
 file.createNewFile();
 fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
 image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, fOut);
 fOut.flush();
 fOut.close();
 MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(), file.getName());

 return file;

 } catch (Exception e) {
 return null;
 }
```

I am displaying some information about failing to save and etc for user if I get null from this method. I though this should be sufficient, yet I got reported `OutOfMemory` crash by one user from this method. Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:527)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:301)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:326)
at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.insertImage(MediaStore.java:796)
at com.stancedcars.wallpapers.FullSelected.saveImageToExternalStorage(FullSelected.java:223)
```

I would love to solve `OutOfMemory` issue, but `Bitmap`s are heavy in size, high resolution images, I wouldn't want to reduce quality. More importantly I would like to know why the app crashed even though it was in try catch ?

Comment: do you like to reduce resolution of image? If it, I can help you in that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You catch the generic Exception, while OutOfMemoryError is an Error, which is Throwable as well.

What you got

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    java.lang.Throwable
       ↳    java.lang.Error
           ↳    java.lang.VirtualMachineError
               ↳    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

What you can catch

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    java.lang.Throwable
       ↳    java.lang.Exception
```

So to catch all possible Throwables, you need to catch

```
try {
     //...
} catch (Throwable e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was just what I needed. For some reason I though Exception is the lowest level you can catch :)

Answer (score 1):

Use catch OutOfMemoryError  not Exception!

```
try {
    // your code
} catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once a program goes out of memory it can be hard for it to recover.  You need to think carefully about how to try and clean up when that happens.  For example, in your saveImageToExternalStorage, it doesn't clean up the fOut if an exception occurs inside your try/catch.  So you should do things like put

```
OutputStream fOut = null;
```

outside the try/catch, and then close it in a finally block of the try/catch.  And pay attention to the possibility of further exceptions in the catch of finally blocks.